# PHP - Find repeated strings and group them with counting

Tags: php

I have many strings looking like this:

```
6 (39), 10 (44), 11 (45), 11½ (45.5), 12 (46)
6 (39), 7 (40.5), 8 (42), 8½ (42.5), 9 (43), 10 (44.5), 11 (46)
6 (39), 7 (40.5), 8 (42), 8½ (42.5), 9 (43), 11 (46)
```

I got these results with this code:

```
<?PHP 
$rscat = mysql_query("SELECT `Sizes` FROM `products` WHERE `Category`='$Cat'");   
while($rowscat = mysql_fetch_array($rscat))
{


    $CatSizes =  $rowscat['Sizes'];

    echo "$CatSizes <br>";

}
?>
```

**What I want:** as you can see in the last example the string `6 (39)` is repeated exactly three times, the string `7 (40.5)` is repeated exactly two times.

So I want a result like this:

```
6 (39) - (3)
7 (40.5) - (2)
```

Of course I do not need that just for `7 (41)` and `10 (44)`; I need to find all strings which are repeating and display them in just one row and aside to show how many times they are repeated.

I hope you understand me well.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Advance warning: OP edited their post several times, so there are multiple answers below. I'm leaving them all intact in case others find them helpful.

## Original answer

You can use the `array_count_values()` function for exactly this: it returns a new array with each repeated value as the array key, and the number of times that value appears as the array value. Using your original example, you'd need something like this:

```
$input = <<<EOT
7 (41)
8 (42)
9 (43)
10 (44)
11 (45)
6 (39)
7 (41)
EOT;

$split = explode("\n", $input);
$counted = array_count_values($split);

foreach($counted as $value => $count) {
    echo "$value - ($count)\n";
}
```

Note: I trimmed the number of strings going into `$input` for conciseness, but you get the point. Output from that script:

```
7 (41) - (8)
8 (42) - (6)
9 (43) - (6)
10 (44) - (6)
11 (45) - (7)
8½ (42.5) - (1)
12 (46) - (1)
6 (39) - (3)
```

You might find the [PHP documentation for array_count_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) helpful reading.

## Update #1

OP edited their post, rendering my original answer incorrect. Using their edited version, the correct code is this:

```
$input = "6 (39), 10 (44), 11 (45), 11½ (45.5), 12 (46), 6 (39), 7 (40.5), 8 (42), 8½ (42.5), 9 (43), 10 (44.5), 11 (46), 6 (39), 7 (40.5), 8 (42), 8½ (42.5), 9 (43), 11 (46)";

$split = explode(", ", $input);
$counted = array_count_values($split);

foreach($counted as $value => $count) {
    echo "$value - ($count)\n";
}
```

WARNING: Make sure the items are all separated by commas, not by a mix of new lines and commas. OP: you should choose new lines as in your original version, or choose commas, but don't mix the two if you want this code to work.

## Update #2

OP has asked to modify the solution so it works directly with their SQL query. This is tricky because I don't know exactly what data is coming out, but based on their previous edits the answer is likely to look something like this:

```
$rscat = mysql_query("SELECT `Sizes` FROM `products` WHERE `Category`='$Cat'");
$arrayOfSizes = [];

while($rowscat = mysql_fetch_array($rscat)) {
    $arrayOfSizes[] = $rowscat['Sizes'];
}

$counted = array_count_values($arrayOfSizes);

foreach($counted as $value => $count) {
    echo "$value - ($count)\n";
}
```

Comment: Note: make sure your strings are identical before passing them to `array_count_values()` – that includes whitespace before or after each value.

Comment: Do i have to this `$CatSizes = str_replace(',', '<br>', $rowscat['Sizes']);` with your suggestion at all ? Is there any sense of doing it ? Before i run this i get the data from MySQL looking like this `6 (39), 10 (44), 11 (45), 11½ (45.5), 12 (46)`

Comment: I used your processed output (everything after 'Now i display the results like this') to produce my answer, but if you have the list as commas use `explode()` with a comma rather than `\n`.

Comment: I see you've edited the post now, which rather unhelpfully renders my answer incorrect :)  I'll edit.

Comment: Yes, I see that; I have updated my answer to reflect this. Please make sure your items are all separated using a comma then a space.

Comment: Thank you so much, can you please take a look for one last time at my updated question because i've added how i get the results shown in my question.

Comment: This is really not helpful; you're making my life awfully hard. What exactly have you changed and what do you want me to answer?

Comment: I am sorry for that. I am not sure `$input = "6 (39), 10 (44), 11 (45), 11½ (45.5), 12 (46), 6 (39), 7 (40.5), 8 (42), 8½ (42.5), 9 (43), 10 (44.5), 11 (46), 6 (39), 7 (40.5), 8 (42), 8½ (42.5), 9 (43), 11 (46)";` is how it is in my code. With your answer i think In my code it will be looking like this `$input = $rowscat['Sizes'];` Can you please check out how i get these results.

Comment: I have updated my answer again; I hope this does exactly what you want. Please don't amend your question again :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98490/discussion-between-tony-stark-and-twostraws).

Comment: No it is closer but not what i need. Can we continue our disscusion on chat ?